# Creating group which has shapes in different layers in KineticJS

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I'll try to explain my problem as accurate as possible.

My project has 2 groups ([Group1], [Group2])
I want to have [Button], which toggles [Group1]'s visibility. (setOpacity to 1 or 0)
I want that [Group1],[Group2] to be draggable and anchored to each other.

```
I've tried this way:
I've created 2 layers [Layer1] and [Layer2].
I've added [Group1] to [Layer1]
I've added [Group2] to [Layer2]
When i click [Button], i toggle Opacity of [Layer1]
I've created [MainGroup] and set it to draggable.
I've added [Group1,2] to [MainGroup]. To make them anchored to each other, and i could drag them.
```

but if i use [Group1].getParent() i get [Layer1], instead of MainGroup, why is that? Should i use different logic? I need [Group1].getParent() to return [MainGroup], so i could find another group in it, which is [Group2] and add some shapes to it.

My KineticJS version is: 4.7.2

Comment: You need to post some code.  In you question, you only mention two groups, but then you suddenly mention a third MainGroup.  are group1 and group2 inside of a main group, which in turn is inside a layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest groups like this: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/YmAdJ/

- Create a containerGroup on a layer.
- Create Group1 and add it to containerGroup.
- Create Group2 and add it to containerGroup.
- Make containerGroup draggable.

**The nested groups would look something like this:**

```
// make a container group to hold group1 and group2

var containerGroup=new Kinetic.Group({
    x:20,
    y:20,
    width:225,
    height:100,
    draggable:true
});
layer.add(containerGroup);

// create group1 and group2 inside containerGroup

var group1=new Kinetic.Group({
    id:"g1",
    x:0,
    y:0,
    width:125,
    height:100,
});
containerGroup.add(group1);

var group2=new Kinetic.Group({
    id:"g2",
    x:126,
    y:0,
    width:100,
    height:100,
});
containerGroup.add(group2);
```

**For both Group1 & Group2, you can get a reference to containerGroup like this:**

```
group1.on(“click”,function(){
      var myContainerGroup=this.getParent();
});

group2.on(“click”,function(){
      var myContainerGroup=this.getParent();
});
```

**You can use that reference to the containerGroup, to get a reference to sub-groups like this:**

```
var myGroup1 = myContainerGroup.get("#g1")[0];

var myGroup2 = myContainerGroup.get("#g2")[0];
```

Comment: Thanks, that changed my thinking a bit, and i solved my issue! :)